# Expecting Done error with BASH script

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, raspbian

I am trying to run some simple if/then/elif script, but I'm running into an error

```html
echo $line2
  If  [[ $line2 == "shakespere/mid" ]] ; then
$line2 = "user/samples/mid"
mkdir /home/user/documents/mid
mkdir /home/user/documents/mid/complete
mv /user/samples/shakespere/mid/fulltext.txt  /home/user/documents/mid/complete

  elif [[ $line2 == "shakespere/rnj" ]] ; then
$line2 = "user/samples/rnj"
mkdir /home/user/documents/rnj
mkdir /home/user/documents/rnj/complete
mv /user/samples/shakespere/rnj/fulltext.txt  /home/user/documents/rnj/complete

  elif [[ $line2 == "shakespere/lll" ]] ; then
$line2 = "user/samples/lll"
mkdir /home/user/documents/lll
mkdir /home/user/documents/lll/complete
mv /user/samples/shakespere/lll/fulltext.txt  /home/user/documents/lll/complete

  elif [[ $line2 == "shakespere/misc ]] " ; then
$line2 = "user/samples/misc"
mkdir /home/user/documents/misc
mkdir /home/user/documents/misc/complete
mv /user/samples/shakespere/misc/fulltext.txt  /home/user/documents/misc/complete

  else
$line2 = "user/samples/son"
mkdir /home/user/documents/son
mkdir /home/user/documents/son/complete
mv /user/samples/shakespere/son/fulltext.txt  /home/user/documents/son/complete
  fi
```

I get this error: "Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting "done")"

I'm sure it's something simple, but it's killing me not knowing why.

I've even mad them all if/then statements - nope. no good.

Running on Raspbian - latest update on RPi3b

Answer (score 0):

real simple.. UPPER case I in IF doesn't work.
it must be "if"

sorry, my grammar nazi came out during the writing of the script.